# Hiding variables or using environment variables in .NET interactive

Tags: visual-studio-code, c#-interactive, .net-interactive

I have been using the .NET interactive Notebooks in VSCode. I was wondering if there is a way to hide variables so that values like API keys can be input and not displayed. I know it is possible to set a variable interactively. Are there any other ways?  Also, is there a way to hide a variable from the "Polyglot Notebook" option on the Terminal.